# ORA-01861 Error thrown only when published to IIS

Tags: oracle, iis

I'm having a problem after published a ASMX webservice that querys a OracleDB using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.

When I *debug* the webservice, calling the respective WebMethod, I can run the oracle sql query with no problems! But when I publish it to my IIS 7 server and call the refered WebMethod I get **ORA-01861 error**.

The obvious answer would be the PL/SQL syntax has a "TO_DATE" function not well-formed... **but** how come I can run it in *debug* in my laptop?!?

Both debug laptop and IIS Server are 64bit. And Oracle.ManagedDataAccess dll is 64bit. Already enabled "Enable 32bit Applications" in IIS, already checked that the assembly is correctly registered in GAC_64 of my IIS server.

Runing out of ideas…

Any help would be much apretiated.

Answer (score 0):

I presume NLS settings in databases on your laptop and on the server are different. The one on the laptop matches date format you provide (as a string), but the one on the server doesn't match, Oracle is unable to implicitly convert it to a correct format and thus returns an error.

So - compare those settings. Query `NLS_SESSION_PARAMETERS`, `NLS_INSTANCE_PARAMETERS` and `NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETERS`, such as

```
SQL> select * From nls_session_parameters;

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ -----------------------------------
NLS_LANGUAGE                   CROATIAN
NLS_TERRITORY                  CROATIA
NLS_CURRENCY                   kn
NLS_ISO_CURRENCY               CROATIA
NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS         ,.
NLS_CALENDAR                   GREGORIAN
NLS_DATE_FORMAT                DD.MM.RR
NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE              CROATIAN
NLS_SORT                       CROATIAN
NLS_TIME_FORMAT                HH24:MI:SSXFF
NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT           DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF
NLS_TIME_TZ_FORMAT             HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
NLS_TIMESTAMP_TZ_FORMAT        DD.MM.RR HH24:MI:SSXFF TZR
NLS_DUAL_CURRENCY              kn
NLS_COMP                       BINARY
NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS           BYTE
NLS_NCHAR_CONV_EXCP            FALSE

17 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks in advance for your answer.

Checked NLS settings for both my laptop and server and the results are exactly the same! :(

Didn't work...

Comment: Solved it!

Reason: I was using Oracle.DataAccess unmanaged dll. This means that the IIS App culture is used. So, changed IIS Application culture from "Invariant" to "Portuguese" and it applied the date formats exactly as I have in my laptop.

Never the less, thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm glad you solved the problem! Thank you for letting us know.